# How to correctly handle errors in ASP.NET Core middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a HandlerMiddleware-class, which executes a handler for a specific URL.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace FailTest
{


    public interface IHttpHandler
    {
        bool IsReusable { get; }
        void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context);
    }


    public abstract class HandlerMiddleware<T> 
        where T : IHttpHandler
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public HandlerMiddleware() 
        { }

        public HandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await SyncInvoke(context);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }


        }

        public Task SyncInvoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // IHttpHandler handler = (IHttpHandler)this;
                T handler = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                handler.ProcessRequest(context);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }


            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    } // End Abstract Class HandlerMiddleware


}
```

Now I have a class which implements a handler, e.g.

```
[HandlerPath("/treedata", "GET,POST")]
public class SomeFailingTask
    : HandlerMiddleware<SomeFailingTask>, IHttpHandler 
{
    public SomeFailingTask() : this(null)
    { }

    public SomeFailingTask(RequestDelegate next) : base(next)
    { }

    bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
          // Do something in DB and return result as JSON
          // e.g. SQL with invalid syntax, or a missing parameter
    }
}
```

It works fine as long as there are no errors in ProcessRequest. 
But when an exception is thrown in ProcessRequest, it finishes the request with HTTP 200 OK.

What am I doing wrong ?
I get the exception, in both Invoke and SyncInvoke, but the HTTP request always finished as if everything was fine...

Comment: And what behavior do you want to have in case of exceptions?

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown and exactly where?

Comment: @cassandrad: HTTP 500; DbException (SqlException) in IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest